# PHP preg_match how to grep string between underscores

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have this string:

`mctrn_25595_AdvandSurthree`

and want to parse it to extract the number `25595` into one variable and basically anything behind `25595_` into another variable.

```
$scriptBasename = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$scriptBasename = basename($scriptBasename);
$cuttedName = preg_replace( '/^mctrn_/', '' , $scriptBasename );
$port= preg_match('/[0-9]+/','',$scriptBasename);
$serverName= preg_match('/_"(.*)/','',$cuttedName);

echo($scriptBasename."\r\n"); 
echo($port."\r\n"); 
echo($serverName."\r\n");
```

The result from my command line:

```
php mctrn_25595_AdvandSurthree.php  <<< script filename!
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/bent/Downloads/mctrn_25595_AdvandSurthree.php on line 8
Array
0
0
```

I am currently a PHP novice and yet failing to do "such simple stuff".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the string will always be in the form of `mctrn_[some integers]_[a string of text]` then you could possibly just use [`explode()`](https://php.net/explode) and [`list()`](https://php.net/list):

```
$scriptBasename = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$scriptBasename = basename($scriptBasename);
list($mctrn,$port,$serverName) = explode('_',$scriptBasename);
echo($scriptBasename."\r\n"); 
echo($port."\r\n"); 
echo($serverName."\r\n");
```

Otherwise if you still want to use [`preg_match()`](https://php.net/preg_match), then you could try this:

```
$scriptBasename = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$scriptBasename = basename($scriptBasename);
preg_match('#\_(\d+)+\_(\w+)#',$scriptBasename,$matches);
if (count($matches) > 1) {
    $port = $matches[1];
    $serverName = $matches[2];
    echo($scriptBasename."\r\n"); 
    echo($port."\r\n"); 
    echo($serverName."\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly how it should work. I like the way how you gave multiple solutions.